# how to do exec to running process in background?

Tags: php, excel, file-upload, timeout, exec

I have a huge database (about 3 million rows).
I want to upload more about 1000 rows `.xls` via `page.php`
every rows must be check if it already on database or not. if already, that row can be insert.
but the result is timeout.

may I use exec to solve that problem? so, when the process is run, we don't need waiting for it. the process running in background. and we can do another process. and when the process is done, the result already show in `page.php` (ex: `sucess=1000 rows, failed=0`) may I do that?
please, give me an idea. :(

Comment: Why not just use a `LIMIT` & pagination?

Comment: sorry. I should edit my question.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove process timeout and continue process in background. Store all your result into your database.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ignore_user_abort();
```